# Passing selected table view content to another view

Tags: swift, tableview, cells, selected

I've searched a lot on this topic but unfortunately I didn't find a solution or en example regarding my problem.

I've created an App with a custom table view in it and with an counter in each cell. With two buttons the user can increment or decrement this counter in each cell.

If the user navigates to the next view I would like to hand over just the cells with counter > 0.

You can imagine this scenario as a kind of shopping list.
The first table view displays all the goods, and I can choose an count from each good and the second view should show the summery of my selection.

The question is how to get all the cells where the counter is greater as 0 and is the “prepareSegue”-Method the right place to get this information?
Does anyone have an example how to do that?

Comment: You need to show us your tableView code your datasource array

Comment: Is your data separate from the UI.  I.E are you just relying on the UI controls themselves or when a counter in a cell changes do you hold a data representation of that.  If not I think you need to look into doing that first.  However as said if you show some of the code we can advise better.

Comment: Thanks for yours answers - I thought my problem is more or less a general question that ist not related to my specific app. Is there no demo that shows how to transfer specific custome table cells from one custome table view into another?